# Not getting intellisense for express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, typescript-typings

I installed using

> npm install --save @types/express

and imported in ts file like this

> import * as express from "express";
>   var app = express();

But I am not getting `intelisense` on app variable. Also when I'm compiling code the red line under express on import line disappear. But as soon as I start typing something in file the red line re-emerges. Why is it happening?

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

and this is server.ts file:

```
import * as express from "express";
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: which ide you are using

Comment: Visual studio code

Comment: If it is related to the language developing like VC# app, you could check the setting under TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->the specific language(C#) ->IntelliSense.

Comment: its typescript project

Answer (score 0):

This question helped me solve the same problem. However, I ran `npm install @types/express -D` and ended up with the following in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
      "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   }
```

The `server.ts` file looks fine.